# I cant run my app build in android studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm getting the following error

> 10/28 11:01:11: Launching 'android' on Pixel 2 API 28.
>
> Installation did not succeed.
>
> The application could not be installed.
>
> Installation failed due to: ''cmd package install-create -r -t --full -S 1763468' returns error 'Unknown
>
> failure: cmd: Can't find service: package''
>
> Retry

previously I could run it. But suddenly it's not succeeding in Gradle build. I tried to install on my phone the unsigned apk but that too failed.

**Edit1:**
And I tried running another project. The same error occurred. So the problem is not project-based. It's happening across the whole android studio.

Comment: Have you tried the option Cold boot now in the emulator?

Comment: Yes. Still the same error @Swayangjit

Comment: Can you install other apps in that emulator?

Comment: Can you run in another emulator?

Comment: @EricHo No. I tried in two different phones too

Answer (score 0):

A few steps I would try in such case, first try to **clear & rebuild**, if didn't work, try ***Invalidate Caches/Restart*** from 'file' menu, as I believe there is a big chance it can be happening due to caching issues.

If there is no luck also, try to disable the **instant run** from settings, then rebuild and try again.

Comment: Nothing has changed. Still same error. I cleaned and rebuild the project. Then tried invalidate & restart cache method. And instant run is missing since Android Studio 3.5

Comment: is this happen on a specific emulator or all emulators?

Comment: Across all emulators and physical devices